# Azure Mobile engagement vs Mobile services

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

It seems there is lot of overlap between features provided by both of these services:
contextually-aware smart push notifications 
in-app messaging across all connected devices.

Should we prefer Mobile Engagement over Mobile Servies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what features you want.  Also, don't forget Azure Mobile Apps - an extension to Azure Web Apps (Azure App Service) that has the same mobile properties as Azure Mobile Services, but with App Service advantages.

If your needs are more in-line with enterprise usage - you need data access to on-prem or cloud SQL services, offline sync, enterprise authentication, continuous deployment, A/B testing, an associated web site that uses the same backend - then Azure Mobile Apps (Web Apps) is the right choice.

If your needs are more in the consumer / brand space - engagement analytics and in-app messaging, then Azure Mobile Engagement is the right choice.

Both have application usage statistics and push notifications.

One does not preclude the other.  You could, for example, write the mobile backend and associated web site in Azure Mobile Apps and then bring in the rich engagement analytics that Mobile Engagement to your apps.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Mobile Services/ Mobile Apps and Azure Mobile Engagement are both complementary technologies. Mobile Services provide push notifications using Azure Notifications Hub. Mobile Engagement provides a full 360 degree view about how your mobile app users are using the app using rich analytics and then you can create smart/specific and targeted segments using the collected analytics data. Once you have these segments, you can send both system and in-app notifications but very targeted. Hence the name Mobile Engagement. It is all about increasing your app usage, retention and monetization using smart engagement with Microsoft Azure Mobile Engagement. For more details check this link - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-engagement-overview/.

P.S. I am a product manager on Azure Mobile Engagement services.