# Azure Push Notification Error from IOS Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, azure

I feel I am the first one in the universe trying to get iOS swift working with Azure, not much help out there. 
I followed this [Create an iOS app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started/)
and then [Add Push Notifications to your iOS App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started-push/). I am supposed to be able to do a successful push notification from iPhone, but I get this error. btw: I can get my C# code to trigger in visual studio in my pc (using this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-how-to-troubleshoot/)), so the request seems to be working, but the response sucks. Any one knows how to fix it!!

```
Error registering for notifications:  Optional("Error Domain=com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorDomain Code=-1302 \"{\"message\":\"An error has occurred.\"}\" UserInfo={com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorRequestKey=<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x14cebf780> { URL: http://<mysite>.azurewebsites.net/push/installations/1E32E9B5-E976-4CCD-BD61-D026D3F4FF1C }, com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorResponseKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x14cec54b0> { URL: http://<mysite>.azurewebsites.net/push/installations/1E32E9B5-E976-4CCD-BD61-D026D3F4FF1C } { status code: 500, headers {\n    \"Content-Length\" = 36;\n    \"Content-Type\" = \"application/json; charset=utf-8\";\n    Date = \"Wed, 11 May 2016 21:39:39 GMT\";\n    Server = \"Microsoft-IIS/8.0\";\n    \"Set-Cookie\" = \"ARRAffinity=8d79cd782ff16b44f7f280b76e2bc5564d86e0d1b228227b8e0033f4bb1c4582;Path=/;Domain=<mysite>.azurewebsites.net\";\n    \"X-Powered-By\" = \"ASP.NET\";\n} }, NSLocalizedDescription={\"message\":\"An error has occurred.\"}}")
```

**UPDATE #1**
The only url I have is the one per the tutorial. The rest of the code is identical to the ones I mentioned in the links (I copied it character by character):

```
class ClientManager {
    static let sharedClient = MSClient(applicationURLString: "http://<mysite>.azurewebsites.net")
}
```

**UPDATE #2**
@Pau Senabre I am working with swift not Objective-C per my question (see my tags under question), so I don't have an .m file per your step #1. I also don't have the logErrorIfNotNil you mentioned. My method (which is generated by Azure before modifications) looks like this:

```
@IBAction func addItem(sender : AnyObject) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("addItem", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!)
{
    if segue.identifier == "addItem" {
        let todoController = segue.destinationViewController as! ToDoItemViewController
        todoController.delegate = self
    }
}
```

**UPDATE #3**
@Pau Senabre My goal is to do mobile apps/services, not mobile engagement. See the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32952488/1019042). btw: I had followed the azure engagement example when I started playing with it and had worked for me. But my need now is web/mobile apps. So, does what you suggested still apply for my need?

Comment: Similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35398851/ios-push-notification-on-azure-notification-hubs

Comment: completely different, how is it similar!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the proper answer from another question I had earlier, which fixes both: Registration and Receiving push notifications. I said this in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37127006/how-to-debug-a-test-send-in-azure):

I finally have been able to receive notifications last night. I went ahead and redid an entire walk-through of all apple-side installation steps using this tutorial: Sending push notifications to iOS with Azure Notification Hubs then the azure-side of things using this: Create an iOS app and Add Push Notifications to your iOS App. That took care of the registering the app of the device successfully, which I was able to verify using the note of AdrianHall in this thread. But that wasn't enough. The Azure tutorials fell short detailing the steps needed in Xcode, which I found here: [How To] Setup Remote Push Notification in iOS - Swift 2.0 Code I didn't have to setup any "push notification" in Xcode or anything like that.

I hope this detailed answer will save you many hours of digging through.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please post some code? I think you may be using a wrong URL in a certain place.

Comment: Uhm, where's your ApplicationKey entry? From personal experience with Azure and Xamarin Forms I know that Microsoft's documentation sometimes is a bit wonky (if you look at the screenshot they provided you'll see it's still at iOS 6 so it's quite outdated), without an application key you can't properly authenticate and thus you can't get access to the Notification Hub.

Try changing your sharedClient initializer to MSClient(applicationURLString: "[url]", applicationKey: "[key]")

Comment: with all the changes to the azure portal, many things got missed. I can't find the application id.

Comment: Try looking in the Application Settings of your Mobile App or go to https://[mysite].scm.azure-mobile.net/Env and check the Enviroment Variables section

Comment: I just created a completely new Mobile App in Azure and found that it didn't have an ApplicationKey anymore, the project I'm working on for work is about a year old now and at that time they were still using the Application Key for logging in

Comment: Unlike Mobile Services, you no longer need an application key with Mobile Apps (unless you explicitly add that functionality to your backend), so that won't be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To **UPDATE #2** 
Check the following link: 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/mobile-engagement/mobile-engagement-ios-swift-get-started.md

In section **Modify your Application Delegate** make sure you create a reach module and your existing Engagement initialization has all the init Values.

```
EngagementAgent.init("Endpoint={YOUR_APP_COLLECTION.DOMAIN};SdkKey={YOUR_SDK_KEY};AppId={YOUR_APPID}", modulesArray:[reach])
```

---

The error Code provided `Error Domain=com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorDomain Code=-1302` matches to a bad request. If you are entering some data, make beforehand a Data Input Validation:

**1** In the TodoService.m file, locate the addItem method search for the [self logErrorIfNotNil:error]; line of code. Beneath that line of code, replace the remainder of the completion block with the following code that checks to see if there was an error in the request and if that error code was –1302, indicating a bad request:

```
BOOL badRequest = ((error) && (error.code == -1302));

// detect text validation error from service.

if (!badRequest) // The service responded appropriately

{

    NSUInteger index = [itemscount];

    [(NSMutableArray *)itemsinsertObject:result atIndex:index];

    // Let the caller know that we finished

    completion(index);

}
```

**2** Build and run; you can see in the Xcode output window that the bad request error from the service was handled:
**2012-10-23 22:01:32.169 Quickstart[5932:11303] ERROR Error Domain=com.Microsoft.WindowsAzureMobileServices.ErrorDomain Code=-1302 “Text length must be under 10″ UserInfo=0x7193850 {NSLocalizedDescription=Text length must be under 10, com.Microsoft.WindowsAzureMobileServices.ErrorResponseKey=, com.Microsoft.WindowsAzureMobileServices.ErrorRequestKey=https://task.azure-mobile.net/tables/TodoItem>}**

**3** Finally, in the `TodoService.m` file, locate the `logErrorIfNotNil` method, which handles the logging of errors to the output window. Inside the if code block, just below the line `NSLog(@”ERROR %@”, error);` add the following if block:

```
// added to display description of bad request

if (error.code == -1302){

    UIAlertView *av =

    [[UIAlertView alloc]

      initWithTitle:@”Request Failed”

      message:error.localizedDescription

      delegate:nil

      cancelButtonTitle:@”OK”

      otherButtonTitles:nil

     ];

    [av show];

}
```

Aditionally, review the following steps in the Azure Setup, maybe you are missing something at some point:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started-push/

**1 Create a Notification Hub**

[image]

This creates a new notification hub and connects it to your mobile app. If you have an existing notification hub, you can choose to connect it to your Mobile App backend instead of creating a new one.

**2 Register app for push notifications**

Register an App ID for your app. Create an explicit App ID (not a wildcard App ID) and for Bundle ID, use the exact Bundle ID that is in your Xcode quickstart project. It is also crucial that you check the Push Notifications option.

Next, configuring push notifications. You may create either a "Development" or "Distribution" SSL certificate (remember to select the corresponding option in the Azure portal later.)

**3 Configure Azure to send push notifications**

In the Azure portal, click Browse `All > App Services > your Mobile App backend > Settings > Mobile > Push > Apple Push Notification Services > Upload Certificate`. Upload the .p12 file, selecting the correct Mode (corresponding to whether the client SSL certificate you generated earlier was Development or Distribution.)

**4 Update server project to send push notifications**
Replace the `PostTodoItem` method with the following code:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostTodoItem(TodoItem item)
{
    TodoItem current = await InsertAsync(item);
    // Get the settings for the server project.
    HttpConfiguration config = this.Configuration;

    MobileAppSettingsDictionary settings = 
        this.Configuration.GetMobileAppSettingsProvider().GetMobileAppSettings();

    // Get the Notification Hubs credentials for the Mobile App.
    string notificationHubName = settings.NotificationHubName;
    string notificationHubConnection = settings
        .Connections[MobileAppSettingsKeys.NotificationHubConnectionString].ConnectionString;

    // Create a new Notification Hub client.
    NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient
    .CreateClientFromConnectionString(notificationHubConnection, notificationHubName);

    // iOS payload
    var appleNotificationPayload = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + item.Text + "\"}}";

    try
    {
        // Send the push notification and log the results.
        var result = await hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(appleNotificationPayload);

        // Write the success result to the logs.
        config.Services.GetTraceWriter().Info(result.State.ToString());
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        // Write the failure result to the logs.
        config.Services.GetTraceWriter()
            .Error(ex.Message, null, "Push.SendAsync Error");
    }
    return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
}
```

Comment: you seem to be able to rescue me. See my Update#2 please

Comment: did you see my last question: Update#3?